# Using MongoLab with Mongoose and models using ObjectIds

Tags: heroku, mongoose, mlab, objectid

I'm using **MongoLab add-on** on **Heroku**.
My app use Mongoose and According to the docs the document id type is ObjectID (by default).

This is why my json looks something like that:

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c824d6f26327e00f9ae117"),
    "company" : "53c824d6f26327e00f9ae118",
...
}
```

The problem: MongoLab addon does not khow how to parse the keyword **"ObjectID"**, displaying an error message.

Am i missing something here? What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the JSON editor in the MongoLab web UI, it only accepts strict JSON formatting. For special types like ObjectId's and dates, you need to use their associated [extended JSON format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). For an ObjectId, that would look like:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": {"$oid": "53c824d6f26327e00f9ae117"},
  "company": "53c824d6f26327e00f9ae118",
  ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps! You can always feel free to write us at support@mongolab.com for any questions or issues.

Kind regards,
Sean@MongoLab